# Blank space in left sidebar of wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, semantic-ui

Ok this problem has had me scratching my head for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. I am customizing the Theme Options page for my WordPress theme and the WordPress Sidebar now has a blank space below the menu items.

**My Question:** How do I return the space below the sidebar menu items back to normal?

I know the problem is something to do with semantic.css (linked below) but I have yet to figure it out. Please help!?

A saved state of my WordPress Dashboard: http://stackoverflow.gopagoda.com 
The semantic.css file: http://stackoverflow.gopagoda.com/index_files/semantic.css

Comment: If you don't have any HTML below PHP, you're including files, try removing the `?>` tag(s). Sometimes that is what the cause is. Also look for any `<br>` or `\n`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- In short, nope.

Comment: What is normal like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the white space between the sidebar menu and the black div block positioned absolutely at bottom-left, then you can do

```
#wpwrap #adminmenuback{z-index:initial}
```

Originally this was set to -1, making `#adminmenuback` covered by other elements with a white background.